# using directshow to snapshot image

Tags: c++, directshow

I'm using windows win7 64bit + windows 7.1 SDK + webcam

when I use the smaple code at \Samples\multimedia\directshow\capture\playcap

it runs fine, but the question is I want to get the image data for bitmap,

it seems I need to include "qedit.h" for ISampleGrabber,

but thereis no "qedit.h" in any folder, I try to make "qedit.h" as following:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/2ab5c212-5824-419d-b5d9-7f5db82f57cd/qedith-missing-in-current-windows-sdk-v70?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment

but it compile error, "identifier 'ISampleGrabber"

is it possible to using directshow to get image data by win7 SDK??

best regards!!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft deprecated that part of SDK, but the Sample Grabber filter itself is still present in modern Windows, including Win 8. Last version of Windows SDK which had Qedit.h is 6.0 but even there it required some old version of DirectX SDK. You can just use this [SampleGrabber.h](http://www.infognition.com/blog/2013/SampleGrabber.h) which is a small excerpt from original headers. More details in [this post](http://www.infognition.com/blog/2013/accessing_raw_video_in_directshow.html).